# Remove existing file from certain location if ansible task fail

Tags: ansible

How to implement to remove a file from certain location when my condition fail.

```
  - set_fact:
      mysql_dump_file: "{{ db_name }}_backup-{{ ansible_date_time.iso8601 }}.sql"

   - name: create backup of the EMS database
     shell: " mysqldump --single-transaction --triggers --routines --events --hex-blob --complete-insert -h {{ db_name }} -u {{ db_user }} -p{{ db_password }} {{ db_name }} > {{ vars.inventory_dir }}/../{{ mysql_dump_file }}"
     register: db_backup_done

   - name: Fail play if database backup fail
     fail:
       msg: 'The database {{ db_name }} backup fail.'
     when: "db_backup_done.rc != 0"
```

I just want to remove "mysql_dump_file" if play fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use an ansible block. This makes it more clear what you are doing.

```
-block:
  - set_fact:
    mysql_dump_file: "{{ db_name }}_backup-{{ ansible_date_time.iso8601 }}.sql"
  - name: create backup of the EMS database
    shell: " mysqldump --single-transaction --triggers --routines --events --hex-blob --complete-insert -h {{ db_name }} -u {{ db_user }} -p{{ db_password }} {{ db_name }} > {{ vars.inventory_dir }}/../{{ mysql_dump_file }}"
    register: db_backup_done
  - name: Fail play if database backup fail
    fail:
    msg: 'The database {{ db_name }} backup fail.'
    when: "db_backup_done.rc != 0"
  rescue:
    - name: Remove the mysql_dump_file if db backup failed
      file: path={{ mysql_dump_file }} state=absent
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add "`ignore_errors: yes`" to the "create backup of the EMS database" task, so that the play will not fail if the command fails and you can use the same "`db_backup_done.rc != 0`" condition to remove the backup file.

```
   - name: create backup of the EMS database
     shell: " mysqldump --single-transaction --triggers --routines --events --hex-blob --complete-insert -h {{ db_name }} -u {{ db_user }} -p{{ db_password }} {{ db_name }} > {{ vars.inventory_dir }}/../{{ mysql_dump_file }}"
     register: db_backup_done
     ignore_errors: yes

   - name: Remove the mysql_dump_file if db backup failed
     file: path={{ mysql_dump_file }} state=absent
     when: "db_backup_done.rc != 0"
```